# SAS: how to check if a column, in an imported excel sheet, contains a string?

Tags: sas

I have imported a dataset from a an excel sheet, and I want to delete some observations. Say, I have a variable which tells me if a student has passed or not (with strings "Passed" and "Failed"). I want to delete all the students which have failed from the dataset.

I do know that usually I would be able to do so with an if statement. However, I don't know how to access the temporary dataset. Do I have to open after importing it, and then check with an if statement?

This is how I have tried:

```
proc import datafile="C:\Users\User\Desktop\testresults.xlsx"

DBMS=XLSX; 

if Status = "failed" then delete

run;
```

I know this won't work as the "if" condition only works when the data resides in PDV.

Is it possible to delete after importing instead of while importing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `where` statement would modify the output dataset from PROC IMPORT, as DomPazz shows.

Alternately, you can use a data step.

```
proc import datafile="C:\Users\User\Desktop\testresults.xlsx" out=have DBMS=XLSX; 
run;

data want;
set have;
if Status = "failed" then delete;
run;
```

That of course would work whether you did it immediately after importing (or in the same submit) or some time later.

Comment: By doing this I create a new dataset?

Comment: Yes, any data step creates a new dataset, although if you name it the same as the old dataset it will simply replace it.  I encourage you to create a new one, though, as it makes debugging easier.

Comment: Have tried to replace replace it, but then it deletes all the variables except "Status", and it only has 1 observation. `data have ;
set have;
if Status = "failed" then delete;
run;`

Comment: Did you specify `data=have` on the `proc import` as I did? Otherwise the name will be something different.

Comment: Yes, I did it like you - Only difference is that I used the same name, so I can replace instead of creating a new dataset

Comment: `proc import datafile="C:\Users\User\Desktop\testresults.xlsx" DBMS=XLSX out=have; 
run;

data have;
set have;
if Status = "failed" then delete;
run;`

Comment: Yep, that should be fine. That sounds like you have some other issue then.  But if you're really just going to run all that, I'd do what Dom said and use `where` directly in the proc.

Comment: Why do I have to delete the old dataset before it will work?

Comment: @Bab You do not have to delete anything, but note that you shouldn't use 'data have; set have' as you've done. That's really bad practice and leads to issues with debugging as mentioned above. Why do you want to do it ?

Comment: @Bab You can add `replace` to your `proc import` and it will automatically replace it.

Answer (score 3):

Use a where clause on the output data set:

```
proc import file="my.xlsx"
            out=work.myxlsx(where=(status^="failed"))
            dbms=xlsx
            replace;
run;
```

Comment: Is it possible to do after importing the data? You know, in case I have already imported it.